# Create script to find which tables have duplicate records in a database?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

In mySQL I want to create a script that will generate tell me the list of tables that have duplicates.
If I have to find which tables have duplicates I will have go to each and every table and run the script 
    `select count(*) from TableA`
then do
 `select select distinct count(*) from TableA`

If its same then that table does not have duplicates else it has duplicates.
I can even get the list of table names from Information_schema.

```
select * from information_schema.tables  where table_type = 'base table'
```

This might be needing a stored procedure I think.
I tried:

```
        DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE duplicates
   BEGIN
set @i = (SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM tableA);
set @j = (select distinct count(*) from tableA);
  if (@i = @j)
    then
    select 1;
      else 
      select 0;
end if
END//
 DELIMITER ;
```

Can you please help me out with this. 
Completely different approach also is fine.

Comment: What database you using? You said mysql in your post, but reference SQL Server and Oracle too

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Comment: i mentioned sql server and oracle as i assumed code might be similar

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags. It just confuses people and wastes their time

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your selects won't find duplicates but if you are happy that they do you can build code for submission to sql from information_schema.tables,(you may find at this point your tables use reserved words). In my example below I use a cursor to iterate through the tables and write the result to a debug_table.

```
drop procedure if exists tablecounts;
delimiter $$
CREATE  procedure `tablecounts`()

begin

declare  i int;
declare   j int;
declare   vtable varchar(100);
declare done int default 0;
declare cur cursor for select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'sandbox'  and table_type = 'base table' and table_name <> 'check';
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
open cur;
truncate table debug_table;
cursorloop:loop
    fetch cur into vtable;
    if done = true then  
        leave cursorloop;
    end if;  
    set @sql = (concat
     (
     'insert into debug_table(msg,msg2) '
     'select ', char(39),vtable, char(39), ', case when cnt1 <> cnt2 then ', char(39),'duplicates exist',char(39),' else null end msg',
     ' from (select (select count(*) from ', vtable, ') as cnt1, (select distinct(count(*)) from ', vtable, ') cnt2) s;'
     )
     );
     #select @sql;

    prepare sqlstmt from @sql;
    execute sqlstmt;
    deallocate prepare sqlstmt;

end loop cursorloop;
close cur;


end $$

delimiter ;

call tablecounts();
```

Debug_table schema.
    CREATE TABLE `debug_table` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `msg` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
      `MSG2` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    )

Comment: Nope MySQL what makes you think otherwise.

Comment: Why do you have `truncate table debug_table;` in the script? when I call the sp it gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

A few points to consider rather than a solution.

First, you will never find duplicate rows in **ANY** table with a PRIMARY KEY because, by definition, the PK is unique.

Second,

```
select distinct count(*) from TableA;
```

will not work because that will give you the *DISTINCT results from the COUNT()* and not the *COUNT() of DISTINCT results*. You'll get the same result as a straight count(*). You'd need to get the distinct rows first and then count them.

In this example I have table with 1,000,001 rows. I've intentionally added one duplicate to an otherwise unique set of records and removed the primary key (otherwise there would be no duplicates).

```
-- REMOVE PK to set up test
mysql> alter table sbtest1 drop column id;
Query OK, 1000001 rows affected
Records: 1000001  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

-- straight COUNT(*) of rows
mysql> select count(*) FROM onemillion.sbtest1;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  1000001 |
+----------+

-- WRONG ANSWER
mysql> select distinct count(*) FROM onemillion.sbtest1;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  1000001 |
+----------+

-- CORRECT ANSWER
mysql> select count(*) FROM (select distinct * from onemillion.sbtest1) a;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  1000000 |
+----------+
1 row in set (52.39 sec)
```

Third point, if you look at the time it took for that final query you'll see that counting rows is not a quick operation.

Fourth, and granted this is pretty contrived, if you decide to exclude the PK column(s) from consideration and do the check on the basis of the other columns how would you handle columns with UNIQUE constraints given that these will allow NULL?

Given this table

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `a` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `b` (`b`)
);
```

Are these rows equivalent when the values in `b` are 'unique'?

```
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
|    1 | NULL |
|    1 | NULL |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

MySQL thinks they are

```
mysql> select count(*) from table1;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        2 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from (select distinct * from table1) a;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

### Update

Here's a solution testing a single table, it could be called by another procedure that gets the table names.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dupes //
CREATE PROCEDURE dupes (IN sname VARCHAR(64), IN tname VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
  DECLARE cols TEXT;
  SET @rcount := 0;
  SET @dcount := 0;

-- Get all the non PK columns in target table
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`column_name`) INTO cols
  FROM `information_schema`.`columns`
  WHERE `table_schema` = sname
  AND `table_name` = tname
  AND `column_key` != 'PRI'
  ORDER BY `ordinal_position` ASC;

  SET @rsql = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @rcount FROM `', sname, '`.`', tname, '`');

  PREPARE stmt1 FROM @rsql;
  EXECUTE stmt1;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

  SET @dsql = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @dcount ', 
                     'FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ', cols , ' ', 
                           'FROM `', sname, '`.`', tname, '`) der');
  PREPARE stmt2 FROM @dsql;
  EXECUTE stmt2;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;

  SELECT CONCAT(@rcount, ' rows: ', @rcount - @dcount, 
                ' duplicate(s) found in `', sname, '`.`', tname, '`' ) AS 'Check duplicate rows';

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Which returns

```
mysql> call test.dupes('onemillion','sbtest1');
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Check duplicate rows                                         |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1000001 rows: 1 duplicate(s) found in `onemillion`.`sbtest1` |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (12.88 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting me with the query. But checking for duplicates in each and every table is a tedious process so looking for a script that will do the whole process in any database I need.

Comment: I think we've all had that problem at some time but usually with a clear idea of the table and specific columns to compare. Looking for a generalised method will require you to first generate a column list without the primary key because it will stop you identifying duplicates in the other columns, you can't do this exercise with a wildcard and DISTINCT.

Comment: @genie I've updated my answer with a solution for testing a single table, you can call it from another procedure which gets the tables.